# How do I correctly install the Facebook SDK Unity plugin?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

My current process is approximatly:

I start with a Disk image of Window 7 x64 with only:

```
Unity 4.3.3f1, Located 'C:\Program Files(x86)\Unity'.
The adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030. 'C:\Users\Will\adt...'.
The Java 32bit runtime 1.7.0_51-b13, 'C:\Program Files(x86)\Java'.
'C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jr7\bin;' is manually added to my 'Path' Environment Varible.
```

As it is I can cleanly deploy Android projects, however I want to use the official Facebook SDK plugin. At this point on my first attempt to install the plugin I dropped it into a project as per the official 'Getting Started' tutorial and this is where I get a bit lost. Even though there is no mention of it in the 'Getting Started' tutorial I find that OpenSSL is a dependancy of the SDK.

So I install the OpenSSL binary 'Win32OpenSSL-1_0_1f' to 'C:\Program Files(x86)\OpenSSL-Win32' and when the plugin still can't find it I add 'C:\Program Files(x86)\OpenSSL-Win32\bin;' to my 'Path' Environment Variable.

At this point The plugin's 'Debug Key Hash' starts working and I naievly assume that everything is correct, However; When I attempt to deploy a build I recieve the following error:

```
Error building Player: Win32Exception: ApplicationName='C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javac.exe', CommandLine='-bootclasspath "C:/Users/Will/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030/sdk/platforms/android-19\android.jar" -d "C:\Users\Will\Documents\Unity Projects\test\Temp\StagingArea\bin\classes" -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -encoding ascii "com\DefaultCompany\test\R.java" "com\facebook\android\R.java"', CurrentDirectory='C:\Users\Will\Documents\Unity Projects\test\Temp\StagingArea\gen'
```

and the build process is halted.

Could anyone help explain where I am going wrong and to get this plugin to behave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same issue - I've solved it by deleting the JAVA_HOME environment variable that pointed to a directory containing JRE (instead of JDK). You also seem to only have JRE installed and the javac.exe file is not part of that package. Alternatively, point JAVA_HOME to the directory on your machine that does have JDK (and javac.exe) installed.

Comment: In this particular case by installing jdk-7u51-windows-i586.exe and creating the JAVA_HOME environment variable as you suggested got it all working smoothly.

Thank you for the help, It is strange that this plugin requires the JDK whiles the rest of the ADT only needs the JRE.